# What would be an .hgignore equivalent for this .gitignore?

Tags: git, mercurial, hgignore

What would be an .hgignore equivalent for this .gitignore?

```
WebSite/wp-content/*
!WebSite/wp-content/plugins/
!WebSite/wp-content/mu-plugins/
!WebSite/wp-content/themes/
```

Comment: JFYI - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmercurial%5D+%5Bhgignore%5D+negative+lookahead for exactly your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [zero-length negative look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like this (syntax approximate :) ):

```
Website/wp-content/(?!(plugins|mu-plugins|themes))
```

but usually you're better off just relying on the fact that `add` *always* overrides ignore, so just put `Website/wp-content/` in your `.hgignore` file and then add everything in those three directories.  The only caveat there is that you have to remember to add any *new* files you put in those directories, but changes to the files you already added *won't* be ignored (because add overrides ignore).

Comment: `q` was a bad paste from the link.  Trailing slash would be fine, of course,

Comment: Cheers for this, not sure how I missed the `(?!...)` in the docs. Should have looked more closely!

Comment: It wouldn't be in the Mercurial docs, just a regex book, and it's a pretty rarely used regex feature.